# The + key takes a screenshot on Mac

Tags: macos, shortcut, screen-capture

When I press the <kbd>+</kbd> key my mac is now taking a screenshot.  Pressing the <kbd>+</kbd> key on the numeric keypad does not do this.  This just started happening and I can't figure out how to debug this to understand what is going on.

Comment: If you open System Preferences/Keyboard and enable "Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar", you get the on-screen keyboard viewer. This will at least check to see if your keyboard is really sending a "+".

Comment: Are you saying when you press the plus key (which is actually `Shift =`), you get a screen shot?  Or is it when you press the `=` key alone?

Comment: It was when I pressed the = key alone.  I fixed it today by simply unplugging the keyboard and plugging it back in :) .  Not sure why I didn't think of that earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Look in System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Screenshots to see if that key is set as a shortcut to take a screenshot. Maybe it got set accidentally. [image: Screenshots preference pane]

Comment: My shortcuts are setup correctly.  Must be something with my keyboard ....

Comment: @Dave, maybe install Karabiner and use its event viewer to see what keys trigger when you press plus.